# En el cmd no ejecuta el comando de flutter

Tags: flutter, cmd

¿Cómo están? Lo que pasa es que quiero instalar flutter entonces estaba en la documentación y me baje la versión del sdk 2.10.4 para Windows ahora la cuestión es que según la documentación ya descomprimí en mi directorio raíz de C la carpeta [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces después de eso se añade a las variables de entorno en mi caso les añadi al path del sistema la dirección del bin
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de eso todo aceptar, pero cuando intento ejecutar cualquier comando de flutter en el cmd se cierra, no me aparecen mensajes de error ni nada sólo se cierra.
Intente darle doble click al flutter.bat dentro de la carpeta Bin pero tampoco pasa nada es como que se abre y se cierra casi al instante no muestra nada... Cualquier persona que tenga una idea de que hacer estaría muy agradecido.
[image: Imagen del cmd después de darle doble click al flutter.bat]
Imagen del cmd después de darle doble click al flutter.bat

Comment: que esperas recibir cuando ejecutas `flutter.bat`? intent escribiendo esto en consola :  `flutter doctor`

Comment: Espero lo que sea la verdad y no me funciona el comando de flutter doctor se cierra el cmd

Comment: intenta esta solución  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69995079/666221

Comment: Me sirvió gracias

Comment: genial,  la voy a traducir y la pongo como respuesta para que ayude a los demás.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega esto a tus variables de entorno en `PATH`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Abre la consola de cmd como administrador y asigna estas variables:

```
setx /M FLUTTER_HOME "C:\flutter" <---- el folder donde se encuentra tu directorio de flutter
setx /M PATH "%FLUTTER_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```